# Add characters into dynamical strings

Tags: java, json, string, java-6

Using Java 6 I get an Array of objects from my db, these objects turn them into **JSON** via `JsonArray.toString()`, but  in my JSP does not interpret correctly because the strings does not have the symbol `'`

This is an example of a string:

```
[[16, 35073, Política/Procedimiento de Backup, Política/Procedimiento de Backup, 100.0], [6, 3802, P, P, 100.0]]
```

Every time es [int, int, String, String, Double] i want to convert to [int,int,'String','String',Double]

How I can make it include `'` at the beginning and the end of the second and third values?

Comment: `thirdValue="\""+thirdValue+"\""` ????

Comment: convert `[int,int,String,String,double]` into `[int,int,'String','String',double]`

Comment: do you have access to JsonArray? is that your class?

Comment: Im usgin this libraries http://www.json.org/java/

Comment: the library itself should take care of that for you. The javadoc reads: "Strings may be quoted with ' (single quote).
Strings do not need to be quoted at all if they do not begin with a quote or single quote, and if they do not contain leading or trailing spaces, and if they do not contain any of these characters: { } [ ] / \ : , = ; # and if they do not look like numbers and if they are not the reserved words true, false, or null."